# Oauth, Twitter and others - Codeigniter PHP

Tags: api, codeigniter, twitter, oauth

I have tried to understand the whole OAuth concept but am failing to be able to progress my application. Lets start with some info about what I want to do:

Firstly, I am writing a blog application in Codeigniter, for myself. On this blog, I want to present some of my shared data from around the web, such as tweets, flickr, 500px photos, sound cloud tracks etc. I am starting with Twitter. I know I can use twitter appltes etc, but I want to this all in native code so that I can understand the whole OAuth process.

Secondly, All of the data on twitter, 500px etc is mine - no one will log into my blog, and therefore I am not interested in "sign in with twitter" type stuff.

Thirdly, I have registered my app with Twitter, and have the Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, an Access Token and an Access Token secret.

Now this is where I think I am going wrong. Lets say I want to grab my own timeline. The twitter API says this needs to be authenticated. Can I not just pass my two keys, and my Access Token to retrieve my timeline.

I have tried all sort of things and keep getting an error of:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Invalid or expired token","code":89}]}
```

I know my access token is correct as I can see it in my twitter api panel.

If I make this call, which I know does not need authentication, it brings back my user details just fine:

```
$user = $this->rest->get('http://twitter.com/users/show', array('screen_name' => 'jamesstoddern'));
```

However, if I try to connect to my timeline with something like this, it fails with the error stated above.

```
$authArray = array(
        'consumer_key' => 'MY KEY HERE',
        'consumer_secret' => 'MY SECRET HERE',
        'username' => 'jamesstoddern',
        'access_token' => 'MY ACCESS TOKEN HERE'
    );

$timeline = $this->rest->get('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json', $authArray);
```

I am obviously doing something wrong, but all of the examples I find seem to be about authenticating other users with a "Sign in with twitter" button, and not about just authenticating your own application silently.

I would be so greatful if someone could give me some pointers or an example that does just what I want it to do.

I am using Codeigniter, and have tried Phils Sturgeons OAuth spark but cannot find suffient examples to help me out. I really find all of this a struggle.

Please can someone explain the steps I need to take to authenticate my own application silently so that I can make calls to my own twitter resources. Once I understand this concept, I should be able to apply the same logic and understanding to connect to my 500px photos for example. I do not want to use twitter specific code and want to make all of this as generic as possible so that I can connect to any API in theory.

Thanks all and sorry for such a long winded question!

James

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but maybe I can help.  I found [this guide](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request) really helpful which explains the steps you need to take to authorize a request.  I have also created a [CodeIgniter library](https://github.com/pattle/codeigniter-twitter-library) for using the Twitter API.  It may be work getting a copy of it and looking through to code to see how its done.

Comment: Cheers Pattle, I'll take a look at the guidance and your library - very useful. Thanks again